# Related to grub rescue

Tags: 18.04

every time I restart my laptop control enters into grub rescue mode, then I have to type the following commands to boot into ubuntu:-

1:-set boot=(hd0,gpt4)
2:-set prefix=(hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub
3:-insmod normal
4:-normal

how to permanently fix this issue? so that I directly boot into ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your bios settings, secure boot feature in BIOS should be disabled.
2. Since you can boot into Ubuntu with commands. Do it, and when you are in Ubuntu:
3. At first try `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`
4. If no success.

   - To find out if you have efi or legacy boot run in terminal:

   `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"`

   - **For efi boot:**

   `sudo grub-install --boot-directory="your boot directory" --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory="your efi directory"`
   Example "your boot directory" = `/boot` and "your efi directory" = `/boot/efi`

   - **For Legacy boot:**

   `sudo grub-install sdx`
   x in sdx being your disc with Ubuntu eg. sda, sdb etc.  You can find this out with `gparted`

   - **Last**

   `sudo update-grub`  and `reboot`